# Downscaled image is drawn in very low quality?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a big logo image (1000x500). I want to use this image and draw it in a frame of size 100x100. Here is how I do it:

```
self.logo = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logoBig")!)
self.logo?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
self.logo?.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width/2 - 50, 50, 100, 100)
self.view.addSubview(self.logo!)
```

This works. The problem is that the image quality is very low after the reduction of the image size.

**How can I draw my big image into a smaller frame without loosing quality?**

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
let logo = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(view.bounds.midX - 50, 50, 100, 100))
logo.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
logo.image = UIImage(named: "logoBig")!
view.addSubview(logo)
```

Comment: What if I want to increase the image afterwards again. How do I ensure that I do not loose quality?

Comment: Change uiimageview frame and set another image or the same image

Answer (score 0):

try using this method

```
 - (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize{ 
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

and if you want to resize the image again, keep the original image and use it for different sizes.

ADD NOTES:
Also, the original image size of 1000x500, resizing it would loose the image's aspect ratio because 100x100 is not propotional to the original image size.

Comment: I use ScaleAspectFit so there is no loose in aspect ratio.